# VB DialogResult doesn't work

Tags: vb.net

I want to make it so when the user is pressing OK button, a code is executed
Here is how I tried it.

The code `foodItemslst.Items.Add(staffForm.TheStaff.ToString)` is NOT executed.

```
      Private Sub AddStaffbtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles AddStaffbtn.Click
            Dim staffForm As StaffForm = New StaffForm
            If (staffForm.ShowDialog = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) Then
                foodItemslst.Items.Add(staffForm.TheStaff.ToString)
                   'the above code IS not executed.
            End If
        End Sub
```

However this code works:

```
  Private Sub AddStaffbtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles AddStaffbtn.Click
        Dim staffForm As StaffForm = New StaffForm
        If (staffForm.ShowDialog = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) Then
        End If
        foodItemslst.Items.Add(staffForm.TheStaff.ToString)
         'The above code is executed
    End Sub
```

There is something wrong with the code:

```
If (staffForm.ShowDialog = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
```

but I don't know what the problem is

The OK button is labeled `OK` and is named `OKbtn`.

Does anyone know why the DialogResult doesn't work?

**Update:**

The code for the OK button,

```
Private Sub OKbtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles OKbtn.Click
        ReadValues(m_staff)
        Me.Close()
    End Sub
```

Comment: show the code for the OK button - are you setting the result?

Comment: It doesn't matter what the OK button is labeled or what it's name is. What matters is that you set the DialogResult property of the button to OK.

Comment: You can add `Me.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK` before `Me.Close()` or set the OK as Dialog Result property of the button.

Comment: Of course!! Thank you soo much!!!

Comment: You don't need the `Me.Close()`.  Just set `DialogResult` with `Me.DialogResult = DialogResult.Ok`...that's all you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set [DialogResult](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/a9527k9a(v=vs.110).aspx), you **don't** need the `Close()` call as well:

> If the form is displayed as a dialog box, setting this property with a
>   value from the DialogResult enumeration sets the value of the dialog
>   box result for the form, hides the modal dialog box, and returns
>   control to the calling form.

So just do:

```
Me.DialogResult = DialogResult.Ok
```